# Send & process .json request (in Rails app)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I have a simple task. User should be able to enter **width** and **height** in a form and after click the form should generate request(link) like following:
 `/find_area.json?width[]=:width&height[]=:height`

App should generate response (**area = height * width**) and display it dynamically on a page.

All user actions have be saved, so it should be POST request.

My questions are:

1. How to create this request (generate it from simple **form_for**).
2. How to calculate area(I mean where:)) and give response.

Sorry for lack of code and information. I will be very glad for quick and simple answer.

Comment: did you tried something?to show link in the url...you need to use GET request without ajax.But my question is how would you show url in the page if its an ajax submit and page should be dynamically updated as well....

Comment: why do you need an array for width and height params?

Comment: @Milind It have to be POST request (in order to save user actions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for small summary about what you need to do using ajax:-

1. create **model** `area` and `migrate` table and use this in `form_for`

   `rails g model Area height:integer width:integer`

   `run rake db:migrate`

   `//view part
   <%= form_for(@area,:url=>"areas/find_area",:remote=>true)  do |f |%>
   <%= f.text_field :width ,:placeholder=>"Enter width",:required=>"true"%>
   <%= f.text_field :height ,:placeholder=>"Enter height",:required=>"true"%>

   <button type="submit"  data-remote="true"> Calculate Area</button>

   <%end%>`
2. add routes in **routes.rb** to handle posting form after submit using ajax

   `match '/find_area', :to => 'areas#find_area'`
3. in **controller** method,get the values from params and calculate area

   `//inside areas_controller.rb,
       def find_area
       width,height=params[:width],params[:height]
        @area=width*height
         respond_to do |format|
          if @area
              format.js 
          else
             format.js { render :json => @area.errors.full_messages.join(' '), :status => 400 }
          end
         end
       end`
4. render **js.erb** to show a pop up /text about the area as well as hide the form using css

   inside find_area.js.erb

   `##using any hidden div already present on the page
      $("#show_area").html("The area is <%= @area%>").show();`